# why it doesnt pass the Bool variable to another Class?

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine

I wanna to open a door when the player's walks around on the trigger switch so i created 2 scripts and I set my Bool Variable on another Class but it doesnt work here is my Code on First class:

```
internal bool openDoor=false;
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D door)
{   
    if (openDoor==true && door.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        StartCoroutine(fading());
    }
}
```

and this is my Second Class that set the openDoor to "true":

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D doorTrigger)
{
    if (doorTrigger.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        LoadLevel03 l3 = new LoadLevel03();
        l3.openDoor = true;
    }
}
```

and when i get back for the door it wont open Although i set the Bool to true.

Comment: I don't know unity, but this code looks suspicious: `bool openDoor=false; if (openDoor==true...)`

Comment: @walkerbox is right. You are creating a new variable in your first method that will always be set to false when you run this method.

Comment: @walkerbox ty for comment please look at it again i moved the Bool on the top and make it Global and still not working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `LoadLevel03`, setting its `openDoor` field to true, then throwing it away again.

You need to get hold of the already existing `LoadLevel03` object in your level.

EDIT: Like this:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D doorTrigger)
{
    if (doorTrigger.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        //find the existing level 3 object and allow it to open
        LoadLevel03 l3 = GameObject.Find("Level3Door");
        l3.openDoor = true;
    }
}
```

Obviously this depends on you setting your level 3 object to have a name of "Level3Door"

ps. `openDoor` is already a boolean, so no need for the comparison in your first method: ie

```
if (openDoor && door.gameObject.tag == "Player")
```

Comment: sorry i dont understand what do u mean can u give example Code? ty